# Discord blacklist with JSON file

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I want to make a blacklist user.id with a json file, when they are using a command, it will send if they're blacklisted or not and if they're blacklisted, it will send the reason

I try this code:

```js
const discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new discord.Client();
const prefix = '+';
const token = 'my bot token';
const blacklist = require('./blacklist.json');

client.on('ready', function () {
  console.log('bot on');
});

client.on('message', function (message) {
  if (message.content.startsWith(prefix + 'check')) {
    if (blacklist.includes(client.user.id)) {
      message.channel.send('you are blacklist, reason: ${reason}');
    } else {
      message.channel.send('heyy');
    }
  }
});

client.login(token);
```

The JSON file:

```json
{
  "user.id1": "reason",
  "user.id2": "reason"
}
```

Comment: Your code is full of syntax errors. No parentheses after `function`, no closing parentheses after if statements. You should fix those first.

Comment: yea, I fix it sorryyy

Answer (score 1):

If the object keys in your JSON file are user IDs, you can use bracket notation to check if the object contains a key, like this:

```js
if (blacklist[user.id]) {
  // user.id exists on blacklist
}
```

Also, I don't think you want to check the `client.user.id`; that's the logged-in client's Discord user. You probably want to check the user who sent the messsage/command, so `message.author`. The following code should work:

```js
client.on('message', function (message) {
  if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix + 'check')) return;

  if (blacklist[message.author.id])
    return message.channel.send(
      `You are on the blacklist, reason: ${blacklist[message.author.id]}`
    );

  message.channel.send('heyy');
});
```

Comment: yes it's anythink like that, but if the author id is in the file, it will chack the reason 
```{
"author.id": "reason"
}
```

Comment: Not sure if I can understand what you're trying to say.

Comment: the reason for your code is the `message.author.id` but I want the reason to be defined in the json like:   blacklisted, reason: spam

Comment: It's still not clear. Have you tried to run the code? It does send the reason correctly.